# How to determine overfitting and underfitting based on loss graph?

Tags: graph, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification, overfitting-underfitting

I'm currently doing my Final Year Project, the classification of Alzheimer's disease stage using a custom CNN model. However, I'm unsure whether my model is overfitting or underfitting according to my loss graph. I have trained the model with 50 epochs with a batch size of 16 and a learning rate of 0.0001 using the Adam optimizer. The confusion matrix seems alright to me. Does my loss graph show the sign of overfitting or underfitting? Here is my:

1. [accuracy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5jOy.png).
2. [loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W4ax.png)
3. [confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMBLq.png)
4. [CNN Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YBWa.png)
5. [Evaluation Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnOfU.png)

If it shows any of these issues, how do I know, and what should I do to improve?

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m teribbly sorry but I’m quite confused regarding my model results. Therefore, I need a few suggestion from the expert regarding this matter as I’m the newbie in the AI field. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: No, you are asking in the wrong site, there is https://ai.stackexchange.com/ for example. Asking off-topic questions can lead to downvotes and bans, do not take it lightly.

Comment: ohhh i see. I don't really know that :) thank you for the heads up!